# how to have a grid inside a grid with 960?

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

i want to have a grid inside a div grid like this one:

http://www.chinolatino.eu/

you can see it has an outer div grid and an inner div grid.

i wonder if this could be accomplished with 960?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This talks about it http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/the-960-grid-system-made-easy/?utm_medium=twitter&utm_source=twitterfeed (see "The Beginning and the End")